# JFrame - mouse click using JComponent and MouseListener

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jcomponent, mouselistener

Having 2 classes  -

```
public class MainClass {



  public static void main(String[] args)  {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    ....
    Component mouseClick = new MyComponent()  ; 
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public class MyComponent extends JComponent implements MouseListener {

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("here was a click ! ");

    }
    ...

}
```

I trying to set on the `frame` a listener for mouse click  , but when I run it and then press mouse click nothing happens  .

How to make it work  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to receive mouse clicks on your frame, you also need to add `mouseClick` to the frame's list of `MouseListeners`. Try adding this line after you create `mouseClick`:

```
frame.addMouseListener((MouseListener) mouseClick);
```